# summation of all elements from an array in python3

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have a array of integers which are space separated like this small example:

```
ar = 1000000001 1000000002 1000000003 1000000004 1000000005
```

I want to sum up the numbers character by character. for example the output for the small example would be:

```
5000000015
```

in fact the sum of the 1st elements from all numbers is 5, and this is the case for all elements.

to get such results I have made the following code:

```
def sum(ar):
    for i in ar.split():
        sum = 0
        for j in range(len(i)):
            sum += i[j]
    return sum
```

but it does not return what I want as output. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: The "sum" is in for loop, which is getting reset to "0" and losing all the prior state information in every iteration.

Comment: "I have a array of integers which are space separated like this small example" That is not an array, that isn't even valid Python syntax. Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your initial "array" is a string, so when you split the array you are still dealing with a list of strings that you can't add to your starting zero value. Also, it is not clear why you are attempting to sum "character by character" when your expected output is just the sum of all the integers. You really just need to convert each integer string to integer and then sum.

```
s = '1000000001 1000000002 1000000003 1000000004 1000000005'

total = sum(int(x) for x in s.split())
print(total)
# 5000000015
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should work

```
ar = "1000000001 1000000002 1000000003 1000000004 1000000005"
total=0
nums=ar.split(" ")
for num in nums:
    total+=int(num)
print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

Capture all the digits first using [`regex`](https://regex101.com/r/OniFw7/1), then pass it to the sum function by parsing it first.

```
import re

ar = "1000000001 1000000002 1000000003 1000000004 1000000005"
pattern = r'([0-9]+)' 

matches = re.findall(pattern, ar)
digit_sum = sum((int(match) for match in matches))
print (digit_sum)
```

Outputting:

```
5000000015
```